# Ensure black/white pages are recognized as such by printer

Tags: color, printing

How can I ensure that the pages I print in black and white with pdflatex are recognized as black and white by a printer in my PDF and not as mixed from CMYK colors?
My question arises because my copyshop explicitly advised me to check whether my black is really a black color or mixed from colors.

Here they said it works without changing anything in macTeX
[Store black and white information in a generated pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124009/store-black-and-white-information-in-a-generated-pdf)

But I am using TexStudio. Does anybody has any experience with that?