Supposed coloring issue when printing a document compiled in latex
I'm in the process of printing my thesis that i have compiled with latex. An issue has emerged that i don't know if it is an existing problem. The owner of the copy shop told me that latex may use a grade of black that is not 100% black but may be 98-99% and that would mean an increase in princing during printing since it would be considered as printing text as color and not black. Is this an actual issue and if so how may i solve this? I'm usig overleaf.
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{sapthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup{labelsep=quad}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\newcommand*{\belowrulesepcolor}[1]{% 
  \noalign{% 
  \kern-\belowrulesep \begingroup \color{#1}% 
  \hrule height\belowrulesep \endgroup }%
}
\newcommand*{\aboverulesepcolor}[1]{% 
  \noalign{%
  \begingroup \color{#1}% 
  \hrule height\aboverulesep \endgroup \kern-\aboverulesep }%
}




\hypersetup{pdftitle={TITOLO TESI}, pdfauthor={Nome Cognome}}
\title{Denervazione renale in pazienti con ipertensione arteriosa come prevenzione primaria e secondaria degli eventi cardiovascolari, neurologici e renali: studio retrospettivo, singolo centro.}
\author{Radovan Lipic}
\IDnumber{1874929}

\course{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Medicina e Chirurgia "E"}
\courseorganizer{Facoltà di Farmacia e Medicina}
\AcademicYear{2023/2024}
\advisor{Prof. Giuseppe Biondi Zoccai}
\customadvisorlabel{Relatore}
%\coadvisor{Dott.ssa Nome Cognome}
%\customcoadvisorlabel{Correlatrice}
%\director{Dott.  Nome Cognome}
%\customdirectorlabel{Specializzando\\Responsabile della ricerca}
\authoremail{lipic.1874929@studenti.uniroma1.it}
\copyyear{2024}
\thesistype{Tesi sperimentale retrospettiva monocentrica}
%\examdate{10 Luglio 2024}


%In caso di titoli di section a 2 righe
%\setlength{\headheight}{22.59052pt}
%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-10.59052pt}

\makeindex
\makeglossaries
\input{glossario}

\includeonly{Cap_1,Cap_2,Cap_3,Cap_4,Cap_5}
\newcommand{\Fig}[1]{[{\footnotesize \texttt{Fig.#1}}]}
\newcommand{\citfig}[1]{\ap{\scriptsize\textrm{(\textit{F#1})}}}

\linespread{1.5} 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\dedication{Dedicato a \\
Mamma e Papà
}

\input{abstract}
\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables

%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronomi}
%\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\mainmatter
\include{Cap_1}
\include{Cap_2}
\include{Cap_3}
\include{Cap_4}
\include{Cap_5}

\backmatter
\cleardoublepage

\newpage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\glossaryname}
%\printglossary

%\newpage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
%\printindex

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography{}

%\newpage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figure}

\input{ringraziamenti}

\end{document}


There are a lot of ways from LaTeX code to PDF and also a lot of ways to define black inside your LaTeX code. So how can we tell without knowing anything about your document or how you generate the PDF? Guess: If it is a b/w document, just tell the owner, (s)he shell print it on a b/w printer, not on a color printer.

I added all the packages in the question and I'm using overleaf

For my own thesis the print shop asked which pages I wanted in color (I had around 10 pages throughout the document with colored graphs and diagrams) and which ones I wanted in black and white, and the pricing was based on that. It is their own responsibility as a professional printer to print black and white pages with actual black ink, even if the document specifies 99% black - they should have postprocessing software and hardware settings for such situations.

Check this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113285/how-to-divide-document-for-black-and-color-printing?rq=1
